# Identify a keyboard with ps/2 bus

Tags: operating-system, keyboard, driver

I am writing a keyboard driver for my custom OS. I have a PCI driver that can return the vendor ID and friends. However I searched on internet if it's possible to communicate directly with the keyboard and identify it directly. I found nothing.

My question is : Can I get a string from the keyboard that identify the keyboard directly using  in / out commands ? ( for example  "Logitech Keyboard" )

The keyboard communicates with a ps/2 interface

Has someone an Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice detailed doc about the ps/2 keyboard protocol: https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf

There doesn't appear to be anything that would tell you some textual identification of the keyboard. I don't think you can even find out how many keys it has.

Short version: no, you cannot.